# SQL JPA - Multiple columns as primary key

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-boot, entity

If i want severeal Column to make up an ID.

SQL example :

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_NAME] PRIMARY KEY ([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])
```

How can i do that with a Jpa Entity class ? through columndefinition ?

just setting the id field as:

```
value = Column1 + Column2 + Column3 // aint working.
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You need to have a class for your composite key:

```
public class CompositeKey implements Serializable {
    private int column1;
    private int column2;
    private int column3;
}
```

and then in your entity class use the `@IdClass` annotation:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CompositeKey.class)
public class EntityExample {
    @Id
    private int column1;
    @Id
    private int column2;
    @Id
    private int column3;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I think this should work.

[There is also the other solution that @jklee mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41144127/11107541). Both work, it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Note that there is a requirement to implement equals / hashCode (see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite)

Comment: How would the `EntityExampleRepository extends JpaRepository< EntityExample, ???>` look like in this case?

Comment: @PrasannjeetSingh EntityExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityExample, CompositeKey> you can take a look at https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-on-composite-ids-in-jpa-entities/

Answer (score 29):

Use `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId`.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId ProjectId id;
}
 
@Embeddable
class ProjectId implements Serializable {
    int departmentId;
    long projectId;
}
```

More information here http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Embedded_Primary_Key_

Comment: Do not forget to implement Serializable ;-)

Answer (score 24):

If all fields in the class are part of primary key, then solution would be pretty simple (extending solution provided by @raul-cuth):

```
@Entity
@IdClass(EntityExample.class)
public class EntityExample implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int column1;

    @Id
    private int column2;

    @Id
    private int column3;
}
```

Comment: What if one of the fields is a FK? It would be a typical scenario when mapping a many-to-many *relationship* table.

Answer (score 4):

1. Using `@IdClass` annotation on the `@Entity` class followed by `@Id` annotation on individual fields that are part of composite primary key.
2. Alternatively can make use of `@Embeddable` class which can consist of individual fields of the composite primary key and then a reference of this class can be used as an attribute with `@Embedded` annotation in `@Entity` class.
   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the hibernate Entity-Class-to-SQL-DDL-Script generator will sort all the fields, and irrespective of the order in which it appears in the definitions, will create the table definition and the index / constraint definitions in this sorted order of the fields.

While the order of appearance of the fields in the table definition may not matter much, the order of fields in a composite index definitely do.  So your key-fields must be named so that when sorted by their names they are in the order you desire for the index).