# How to create a mapping to a SQL table that has no primary key?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have a table where there isn't a primary key. It is expecting an `@ID` annotation and without it, the following error is being thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: 
overall.model.Overall
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
```

I have tried implementing both in JDBC template as well as using `JPA` but I'm not able to create any entity without `@ID` annotation.

The table has all fields of type String. Could you please give a suggestion on how to configure a table to not have a primary key?

I am using a `spring-boot`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143913/sql-jpa-multiple-columns-as-primary-key) should help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the table has no primary key at all, use this workaround: create a *fake* composite primary key, consisting of **all** the columns. I hope there aren't too many of them. For example:

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(UserNRole.InnerIdClass.class)
@Table(name = "users_n_roles")
public class UserNRole {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Integer roleId;
 
    // getters, setters and constructor . . .
 
    public static class InnerIdClass implements Serializable {
        private Integer userId;
        private Integer roleId;
    }
}
```